# Store player stats in mysql with time to get the ranking of the last 30 days with highest value

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

EDIT: I explain it again. I hope you understand it :)

I want to store the player stats into mysql. I want all time stats, every kill, death oder win will saved in the table. And I want stats for the last 30 days, I want a mysql query to get the kills or wins of only one player in the last 30 days. I don't know how to save. And then I want the top 10 of the last 30 days (month) stats.

Comment: add **WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY**

Comment: You should add sample data and desired results.

Comment: added a example table and what I will get

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of players with the highest value by using:

```
select player, sum(wins) as numwins
from t
group by player
order by numwins desc;
```

You can add a filter to get only players from the last 30 days:

```
select player, sum(wins) as numwins
from t
where time > curdate() - interval 30 day
group by player
order by numwins desc;
```

You can add a `limit 1` to get one such player.

If you want all players when there are ties, then the query is a bit more complicated.

Comment: When the player win a round the column wins get +1 but I want the value of wins from the last 30 days. Example: I have 10 wins, but 5 in the last 30 days, then I will only the 5 wins. And then the top 10 of the highest wins in the last 30 days

Comment: Example for the ranking: Player1 with 20 wins in the last 30 days. Player2 with 16 wins in the last 30 days